# How can I get some value of a deep-nested object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

There are two types of arrays which I have to build dynamically.

```
data['fields']['title']
```

and

```
data['fields']['description']['html']
```

it returns the content of this structure:

```
{   
    "fields": {
        "title": "Headline",
        "description": {
            "html": "<p>description text</p>"
        }   
    },   
    "meta": {
        "id": "995915463198380032"   
    } 
}
```

The problem is "dynamically".

I call a function and give the path through it like "`description>html`".
I split the string into "description" and "html".
But how do I build now the array: `data['fields']['description']['html']`

Sometimes there is a level more or less like "title".
If I want to call title, the array is like `data['fields']['title']`

So the content and the number of parts in the array are dynamic.

I tried by myself this:

```
function comfort_x(item_fields) {


var splitter = item_fields.split(">");
var content = new Array();

for (var i = 1; i < splitter.length; ++i) {
    content['splitter['+i+']'] = splitter[i];
}

data['fields'][splitter[0]][splitter[1]];

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you add some sample strings that you might want to try

Comment: take a look at the content structure. these are the strings i want to return.

Comment: So this question is rather about an object than an array. May I suggest the title to “How can I get some value of a deep-nested object?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that will look up to the level you are passing. You can just `split` your path by `>` and reduce that array with the source input.

```
(data, path) => path.split(">").reduce((r, e) => r[e], data);
```

Here is a example.

```js
var obj = {   
    "fields": {
        "title": "Headline",
        "description": {
            "html": "<p>description text</p>"
        }   
    },   
    "meta": {
        "id": "995915463198380032"   
    } 
}

var lookUp = (o, path) => path.split(">").reduce((r, e) => r[e], o);

console.log('fields: ', lookUp(obj, 'fields'))
console.log('fields>title: ', lookUp(obj, 'fields>title'))
console.log('fields>description>html: ', lookUp(obj, 'fields>description>html'))
```

Comment: Makes totally sense for reading an deep-nested key in an object. 

Comment: That's it! Thanky you!

Answer (score 0):

It works with this addinitional work-around:

```
        switch (splitter.length) {
        case 0:
            item.innerHTML = data['fields'];
        break;
        case 1:
           item.innerHTML = data['fields'][splitter[0]];
        break;
        case 2:
            item.innerHTML = data['fields'][splitter[0]][splitter[1]];
        break;
        case 3:
            item.innerHTML = data['fields'][splitter[0]][splitter[1]][splitter[2]];

    }
```

maybe you have a smarter solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
    Be careful! The function won’t return a new object, 
    but take a reference to the input object aka. alter 
    it and don’t deep-clone it.
*/
const myObject = {};

function setValueByKeypath(object, path, value, separator = ">") {
    path = path.split(separator);
    let currentPart = object;
    for (let i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
        const key = path[i];
        const keyValue = (i === len - 1) ? value : {};
        if (typeof currentPart[key] === "undefined") {
            currentPart[key] = keyValue;
        }
        currentPart = currentPart[key];
    }       
}

setValueByKeypath(myObject, "fields>description>html", "<p>description text</p>");
console.log(myObject);

setValueByKeypath(myObject, "fields>title", "Headline");
console.log(myObject);

setValueByKeypath(myObject, "meta>id", "995915463198380032");
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Is meant for building an object by known nested paths.